# generalize Int -> Int, Int-> String, String -> String, String -> Int

Tags: scala, generics

I have 4 methods with one logic and 4 possible type mapping:

```
  def convertStringToString(in: String): String = ???
  def convertIntToString(in: Int): String = ???
  def convertIntToInt(in: Int): Int = ???
  def convertStringToInt(in: String): Int = ???
```

I want to generalize  input and output type and write logic in one methods. Tried to generelize input parameter:

```
  def convertToInt[IN](in: IN): Int = in match {
    case x: String if x.forall(_.isDigit) => x.toInt
    case y: Int => y
    case _ => 0
  }
  def convertToString[IN](in: IN): String = convertToInt[IN](in).toString
```

Could you help me to generalize second:

```
  def convertToInt[IN, OUT](in: IN): OUT = ???
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you're trying to do? Why do you want to generalize functions that are very specific to their input and output types?

Comment: I'd agree with @YuvalItzchakov and also question from my side you have two methods with signature `(in: String): Int` - how you want to distinguish them in "generalized" form?

Comment: @Ivan Kurchenko there was an misprint, updated

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov the methods contains some logic, for example check null and calculations

Comment: Why do you want to generalize this? I really do not see any benefit and rather you would get more confusing code.

Comment: Ok, just interested )))

Comment: Ok, and what is your end goal / interest? learn about generics? learn about abstractions / polymorphism? reduce code duplication? allow extensibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to, you could have something typeclass-based:

```
def convert[I, O](in: I)(implicit c: ConversionRule[I, O]): O = {
  if (c.isConvertible(in)) c.convert(in)
  else c.zero
}

trait ConversionRule[I, O] {
  def isConvertible(in: I): Boolean
  def convert(in: I): O
  def zero: O // Could possibly derive the zero from, e.g., a cats Monoid instance where such exists
}
```

The eagle-eyed may notice that the `isConvertible`/`convert` methods match the contract of `PartialFunction[I, O]`'s `isDefinedAt`/`apply`, so may as well just use `PartialFunction` (and rewrite `convert` with `isDefinedAt`/`apply`)

```
trait ConversionRule[I, O] extends PartialFunction[I, O] {
  def zero: O
}
```

`zero` can be implemented in terms of `PartialFunction.applyOrElse`, but for the case where `zero` is constant (which is the case where referential transparency is preserved), this is much faster.

Smart constructors can be defined:

```
object ConversionRule {
  def apply[I, O](zeroValue: O)(pf: PartialFunction[I, O]): ConversionRule[I, O] =
    new ConversionRule[I, O] {
      override def apply(i: I): O = pf(i)
      override def isDefinedAt(i: I): Boolean = pf.isDefinedAt(i)
      val zero: O = zeroValue
    }

  def totalConversion[I, O](f: I => O): ConversionRule[I, O] =
    new ConversionRule[I, O] {
      override def apply(i: I) = f(i)
      override def isDefinedAt(i: I) = true
      override def zero: O = throw new AssertionError("Should not call since conversion is defined")
    }

  // Might want to put this in a `LowPriorityImplicits` trait which this object extends
  implicit def identityConversion[I]: ConversionRule[I, I] =
    totalConversion(identity)
}
```

`identityConversion` means that a `convertIntToInt` gets automatically generated.

`convertStringToInt` can then be defined as

```
implicit val stringToIntConversion = ConversionRule[String, Int](0) {
  case x if x.forAll(_.isDigit) => x.toInt
}
```

One can define a `toString` based conversion (basically the non-lawful `Show` proposed for alleycats):

```
implicit def genericToString[I]: ConversionRule[I, String] =
  ConversionRule.totalConversionRule(_.toString)
```

And it should then be possible to define a `stringViaInt` `ConversionRule` derivation like:

```
implicit def stringViaInt[I, O](implicit toInt: ConversionRule[I, Int]): ConversionRule[I, String] =
  convert(convert(in)(toInt))
```

The only really useful thing this provides is an opt-in to usage of implicit conversions.  Whether that's enough of a gain to justify?  *shrug*

(Disclaimer: only the scala compiler in my head has attempted to compile this)

Comment: I would instead provide an `attemptConvert` abstract method which returns an **Option** and a concrete _(and maybe `final`)_ `convert` method that calls `getOrElse`. And a factory constructor taking a **PartialFunction**.

Comment: Just for personal curiosity: Does it really worth the effort rather then to have 4 explicit conversions methods? But looks amazing really.

Comment: It's a good question whether this is worth the effort.  This does generalize to arbitrarily many conversions, so maybe.  The big win is being able to opt-in to implicit conversions (`convert` itself might even be able to be made implicit), and more questionably, the ability to lift a `PartialFunction` into an implicit conversion.